# Canonical divisor of Hirzebruch surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, minimal-surfaces

I want to describe push-forward of the relative canonical divisor of $\mathbb{F}_n:=\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}(n)\oplus \mathcal(O))$ via the projection 
$\pi:\mathbb{F}_n\to\mathbb{P}^1,$ but I don't know which is the canonical divisor
$K_{\mathbb{F}_n},$ and clearly I need it, so any help to how compute or describe 
this divisor will be so much usefull for my.

Thank you.

Comment: You mean $n$ instead of $1$ right ?

Comment: Yes!, I will change that mistake.

Comment: Also, I'm a bit lazy to do the computations so I'm only posting a comment but here are at least two ways of computing it : 1) Hirzebruch surfaces are toric varieties, and there is an easy formula for canonical divisors on toric varieties. 
2) [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559927/canonical-sheaf-projective-bundle) explains how to compute the canonical divisor of a projective bundle.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Thank you, for your comment, :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anti canonical divisor of a toric surface may be represented as a sum of all the *boundary divisors*, i.e. torus invariant curves corresponding to the edges of the associated Delzant Polygon. Hence $K_{X}$ is minus the sum of all boundary divisors.  In the case of a Hirzebruch surface $\mathbb{F}_{n}$ the boundary divisors consist of the two sections $S_{1},S_{2}$ (with $S_{1}^{2} = n$ and $S_{2}^{2} = -n$) and two copies of a fibre of the $\mathbb{P}^{1}$-bundle say $F$ with $F^{2} = 0 $, and $F \cdot S_{i} = 1$ for $i = 1,2 $.

So in summary $$K_{X} = - 2F -S_{1} -S_{2} .$$