# Canonical bundle of cyclic covering

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $Y$ be a complex manifold and $0\neq f\in H^0(Y,L^d)$, where $d\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}$ and $L$ is a holomorphic line bundle over $Y$. Then it gives a cyclic covering $\pi\colon X\to Y$, where $X\subseteq\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_Y\oplus L)$ is a hypersurface in the total space of projective bundle $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_Y\oplus L)$.

A classical result is that the canonical bundle of $X$ is given by
$$
K_X=\pi^*(K_Y\otimes L^{d-1}).
$$
One way to understand the above formula is the Hurwitz formula, but since $X$ is a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_Y\oplus L)$, I want to use the adjunction formula to explain this. If we denote $\mathcal{E}=\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_Y\oplus L)$ and still use $\pi$ to denote the projection $\pi\colon\mathcal{E}\to Y$, then one has the following [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559927/canonical-sheaf-projective-bundle?rq=1)
$$
K_{\mathcal{E}}=\pi^*(K_Y\otimes\det(\mathcal{O}_Y\oplus L))\otimes\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{E}}(-2),
$$
where $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{E}}(-1)$ is the tautological line bundle. Thus it suffices to compute the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{E}}(X)$. In one [paper](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/mrl/2021/0028/0003/MRL-2021-0028-0003-a007.pdf) I found that
$$
\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{E}}(X)=\pi^*L^d\otimes\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{E}}(d).
$$
Then by adjunction formula, I will obtain
$$
K_X=\pi^*(K_Y\otimes L^{d+1})\otimes\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{E}}(d-2)|_X.
$$
It seems not as desired, and is there any way to compute $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{E}}(-1)|_X$? Thanks in advance for any advice and help!

Comment: Could you elaborate slightly how to establish $X \subset \mathbb P(\mathcal O_Y \oplus L)$? The way I learned cyclic covers is via relative Spec, $X = \operatorname{Spec}_Y(\mathcal O_Y \oplus L^\vee \oplus \dotsb \oplus L^{-d+1})$, where the algebra structure is determined by $f: L^{-d} \to \mathcal O_Y$.

Comment: I think the formula one before last should read ${\cal O}(X)\simeq{\cal O}_P(d)$ (check the construction - $X$ is the vanishing set of a section of ${\cal O}_P(d)$). On the other hand, by construction, $X$ does not meet the hypersurface at infinity of $P={\bf P}({\cal O}_Y\oplus L)$ (the one given by ${\cal O}_Y$). Therefore ${\cal O}(1)|_X\simeq\pi^*(L)|_X$. If you combine these two facts you get $$K_X=\pi^*(K_Y\otimes L)\otimes{\cal O}_P(d-2)|_X\simeq \pi^*(K_Y\otimes L^{d-1}).$$

Comment: @DamianRössler Could you give a more detailed proof about $\mathcal{O}_{P}(X)\cong\mathcal{O}_P(d)$ and $\mathcal{O}_P(1)|_X\cong\pi^*L$ since I still believe the result I found in that paper is correct for some reason. Here is my reason: Since the total space $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_Y\oplus L)$ is the same as the one of $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_Y\oplus L^*)$, but they have different tautological bundles, so I think $\mathcal{O}_P(X)$ cannot only depends the tautological bundles of projective bundle, but also related to $L$.

Comment: @red_trumpet ok I will, after I totally figure out what's wrong with my understanding, a reference about this is the paper I cited in the question, another is    "compact complex surface" written by Barth.

Comment: We have $$V_d:=\pi_*({\cal O}(d))={\rm Sym}^d({\cal O}_Y\oplus L)=\oplus_{k=0}^d L^{\otimes k}.$$ Consider the section $(-1)\oplus\cdots\oplus f$ of $V_d$. This gives a section $\sigma$ of ${\cal O}(d)$ (by adjointness of $\pi_*$ and $\pi^*$)  and the  vanishing set of $\sigma$ is $X.$ The section $1\oplus 0$ of $\pi_*({\cal O}(1))={\cal O}_Y\oplus L$ gives the hypersurface $H$ at $\infty.$ Then $X$ and $H$ are disjoint. To see this, one can argue locally and suppose that $Y$ is affine and $L$ trivial. Then this amounts to saying that $x^d-y^d$ and $y$ cannot vanish toger on ${\bf P}^1.$

Comment: Sorry I just noticed that there is an issue with what I wrote. I will write a complete answer soon.

Comment: @DamianRössler Thanks for your kind help!